# how to increase session timeout over 1 hour

Tags: asp.net, authentication, iis

I want to allow users a longer inactivity timeout setting of over 1 hour. I configured in web.config:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">      
  <forms name="MYWEBAPP.ASPXAUTH" loginUrl="~/Welkom.aspx" protection="All" 
         timeout="181" slidingExpiration="true" path="/"/>
</authentication>
```

The application pool has the advanced setting:

```
Idle Time-out (minutes):   181
```

In the login code I configured the ticket and the cookie:

```
FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = new ...
ticket.expiration = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(180);
...
cookie.Expires = ticket.Expiration.AddMinutes(5);
Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
```

The MasterPage prints the `ticket.expiration` in the footer of each web page, so that I can see what is going on internally.

As is widely known, `sliding expiration` means that the timeout value is incremented only with a GET request after half of the timeout period has passed. I tested as follows:

At login, I see in the footer an expiration time that is 3 hours ahead.

Every once in a while I do something in the web site, but the expiration time does not change.

If I do something when the expiration is less than 90 minutes ahead, the expiration time is updated to 3 hours from that moment.

However, if I wait longer than 60 minutes, and then do something, while the expiration time is still over an hour ahead, I will get the login page.

Does anybody know how to fix this?

Comment: Have you read this S/O article? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3984424/timeout-and-auto-logout-in-asp-net-2-0-with-iis-7-even-after-doing-all-the-possi?rq=1

Comment: @tgolisch Great link! Now I found this SessionState parameter in Web.config. Testing takes a lot of time, expect results tomorrow.

Comment: @tgolisch first test of 90 minutes worked! Why don't you put your link with the missing SessionState parameter in an answer, that I'd be glad to accept?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To configure the Session Inactivity Timeout, there are FOUR settings. In my question I mention three settings, and [timeout and auto logout in asp.net 2.0 with IIS 7 even after doing all the possible settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3984424/timeout-and-auto-logout-in-asp-net-2-0-with-iis-7-even-after-doing-all-the-possi?rq=1) mentions the fourth setting: SessionState parameter in Web.config.